# firebug iframe breaking atmosphere iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, firebug, comet, atmosphere

I have an invisible iframe that is talking to an atmosphere comet broadcaster. It works fine on most of the computers in the office.

On one computer in the entire building it breaks. The problem seems to be that there is an iframe that somehow gets inserted on that machine:

```
<iframe style="position: absolute; width: 5em; height: 10em; top: -10000px;" src="javascript:'
<html>
<head>
<script>if("loadFirebugConsole" in window){window.loadFirebugConsole();}
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>'">
</iframe>
```

(note that most of this html is actually within the src for the opening iframe tag).

That iframe blinks in and out of existence, and when it does it clobbers my iframe that's handling the comet service.

I assume that this has something to do with firebug tools having been installed, but it happens on chrome as well as on firefox.

Has anybody else come across a this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site uses Dojo, and it turns out that, in at least some cases, dojo inserts that iframe if you create an iframe and  have firebug installed on the computer.